# How should I work on a CVS hosted project to both (1) fix bugs and (2) maintain my own private fork with additional features

Tags: version-control, mercurial, cvs

**The question**

An open source program uses CVS for version control.  I would like to make a number of bug-fixes and submit patch bombs to the developers with commit access.  I would also like to maintain my own semi-private fork that mainly tracks the main code-base but that includes my own features (these features, right now, should not be incorporated into the main code-base.)

I prefer to use mercurial for my own version control needs, but I am open to other version control systems if necessary.

I'd like to:

1. Be able to easily create patch-bombs against the current CVS source with my own bug-fixes
2. Keep track of history on my own features
3. Have fixes and improvements from the main tree easily incorporated in my new-feature fork
4. Easily apply my own bug-fixes to my new-feature fork
5. Be able to work and track change history without an Internet connection.

*What suggestions do you have for doing this?*

**My current idea**

My own best guess is below, to give you a better idea of what I am thinking about.

I will have 3 mercurial repositories.

The first two repos are managed as specified at (https://wiki.mozilla.org/Using_Mercurial_locally_with_CVS).   One just mirrors the latest changes from the CVS upstream.  I do "cvs update" then "hg commit" in this repo.  The second repo holds my bug-fixes as patches using the mq extension and I pull from the the first repo and re-base my patches every so often.  When my patches are incorporated into the main tree, I remove the patches from the patch queue/make them permanent commits.

The third repo is my local fork.  It will start out as a clone of the first repo.  Then each time I do an update of the first repo, I'll pull from it into repo 3.  My own features will be directly present as commits in this repo.  When I fix a bug, I'll export a patch from repo 2 and apply it to the appropriate pull from repo 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Git to manage changes on top of a CVS repository in a similar way. My solution in Git uses local branches instead of multiple repositories, but it sounds essentially similar to your proposed idea.

I found that this arrangement works best if you commit all the CVS metadata (in the `CVS/`) subdirectories) to your mirrored repository. This means that the CVS metadata gets replicated in the other repositories, but it doesn't cause any harm (and lets you run commands like `cvs diff` if you need to).